# Add NOPASSWD for a specific command

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I know, there're lots of other posts related to this question. but, that's not a secure way to proceed with. I've initially added `Defaults:apache !requiretty` and set the `script.sh` file path that run by the web user, this `script.sh` invokes another command that should run as `root` user. 
then I added the NOPASSWD like this

```
apache ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/app/admin/tomcat.sh start
```

It gave the following error

```
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 120 <<< sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 120 sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Then, I directly added the command that should run as `root` user. and it becomes

```
apache ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/su root -c /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/bin/startup.sh
```

I also tried to change the command e.g:

```
apache ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/bin/shutdown.sh
```

still the same(above) error.
Although `apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` works well. but there is a security issue.

So, how can I grant a user the access to run a specific command as `root` user?

Answer (score 0):

You'r first line seems to work well, i tried it with no problem, are you sure that the line 120 is the one you are trying to add?
use the command "se: nu" on vi to check if the problem is not from another line just before or after, if it doesn't work ca you post all your sudoers file ?

Comment: No, the following line `apache ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/app/admin/tomcat.sh start` doesn't work. as described above. its line number is 120 in sudoers file.